# Create groups in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How can I create groups in data.table?

I have a data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1=c("A","B","C"))
```

Now I want to add to every realization of V1 a group of strings:

```
myGroup <- c("d", "e", "f")

result <- data.table(V1=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                     V2=c("d","e","f","d","e","f","d","e","f"))
```

Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: dt <- data.table(V1=c("A","B","C"), V2=rep(myGroup, 3)) gives the result. But maybe someone knows how to add the groups afterwards? Thx

Comment: :( Oh Oh, my comment above gives not the right result, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can delete comments that you make that are no longer necessary by clicking on the gray X that appears when you hover over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out <- dt[, .(V2 = myGroup), by = V1]

#    V1 V2
# 1:  A  d
# 2:  A  e
# 3:  A  f
# 4:  B  d
# 5:  B  e
# 6:  B  f
# 7:  C  d
# 8:  C  e
# 9:  C  f

all.equal(out, result)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

**Edit**
Per @Frank's comment, you can equivalently and more idiomatically do: `dt[, CJ(V1, myGroup)]` (`CJ` stands for (C)ross (J)oin).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried `out <- dt[, .(V2 := myGroup), by = V1]`. Which does NOT work :)

Comment: @Frank thanks. I was trying my data.table hand at this somewhat orphan and easy question, but I'm still far from fluent. Will update